# .htaccess Redirect File Extension to another

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I am attempting to redirect the following urls:

```
http://mysite/test.cfm
```

to

```
http://mysite/test.html
```

This is what I have tried.... the regex works in online regex testers but doesn't work in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.*)\.cfm
RewriteRule ^(.*)(?=\.cfm) $1.html [L]
```

It appears that it is trying to redirect to .cfm.html - this doesn't make much sense to me because the second regex tells it not to match .cfm.

Comment: In general, .htaccess files use the same syntax as the main configuration files. What you can put in these files is determined by the AllowOverride directive http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to redirect (ask the client for fetching another document with HTTP code 302) you could use Mod_alias with the following redirection

```
    RedirectMatch (.*)\.cfm$ $1.html
```

Best wishes,
Matthias